# Is there some kind of access control for recorded video in ApiRTC?

Tags: video

When recording a video using ApiRTC the link for the recorded video is accessible to anyone with the video link. Is there are way to password protect the video or limit the access to it only to the people who was part of the conference? If not, is there are API to delete the video?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to manage recorded videos through the MediaManager : https://cloud.apizee.com/media-manager.

From an API perspective, the ApiRTC REST API exposes a /media endpoint with which you can delete (among other things) a recorded video given it's id.